# Removing a Turtle from a List

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I have a list in which each element is a turtle and was trying to make a turtle get removed from the list and get hidden. So far I have tried :

```
lis[lis.index(food)].ht()
lis[lis.index(food)].clear()
lis.remove(lis.index(food))
```

However, when I run this, I get an error saying that the element is not found.

Answer (score 0):

If `lis` is a list of turtles and `food` is a turtle then use `lis.remove(food)`. The error message that you are getting is because `lis.index(food)` is an `int` (not a turtle) and that int isn't in your list.

If you are going to be doing a lot of removing, a dictionary of turtles might be more natural than a list. Removing from a dictionary is `O(1)` but removing from a list is `O(n)`. As a general rule of thumb, if you find yourself repeatedly removing (and/or inserting) items from the middle of a list you should ask yourself if there is a better way of achieving your goal.

Comment: This is in a for loop that is iterating through a list. Food is what I am referencing each element as in the list? Will this still work?

Comment: It is typically a bad idea to use `.remove()` while iterating over a list. The fact that you are making the list shorter with each `remove()` can cause the iteration to skip over elements in a counter-intuitive way. In any event, if you have another question you should post it as another question, preferably one which has a [mvce]